# Merge Zurb Foundation Icon Fonts Into Moovweb

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, moovweb, tritium

I am trying to include Zurb Icon Fonts 3 into my Moovweb project.  First off, is it supported?  Second, what do I have to do to get them to work.  I have tried a few different combinations of importing them, but each time it brings up a blank local host page.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you describe the methods that you have tried?

Comment: Hi @gregorygtseng, currently I have globals/icons/foundation-icons imported into my main.css folder. I did this after adding the icon pack to my globals folder and renaming it icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to create a `fonts` folder under the `assets/images` folder where you would place the foundation fonts.

Then you would include the `foundation-icons.scss` file in the `stylesheets` folder, but rename it so it's a partial: `_foundation-icons.scss`

Edit the references in `_foundation-icons.scss` so they point to `image-url("fonts/foundation-icons.ttf")`, etc.

Then you can `@import "_foundation-icons.scss";` so the styles get compiled in your main stylesheet.